# Can I use spring AOP to log start and end of a method to help easy debuging

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am using testNg to test an application and using SpringTest.

I want to log start and end of each method so that I can debug easily where the failure happened

If I have a method like this

```
public void performUserSignIn(){      
     signInAgent.performSignIn(username,password);      
}
```

and I want to log the start and end of this method like this

```
public void performUserSignIn(){      
     logger.info("started performUsersignIn");
     signInAgent.performSignIn(username,password);
     logger.info("finished performUsersignIn");      
}
```

dong this for  each and every method in my test automation is very cumbersome. Can I use Spring AOP to achieve this? My idea is to create a custom annotation @LogMessage and then use it as such

```
@LogMessage("performUserSignIn")    
public void performUserSignIn(){      
     logger.info("started performUsersignIn");
     signInAgent.performSignIn(username,password);
     logger.info("finished performUsersignIn");      
}
```

or even better like this

```
@LogMessage
public void performUserSignIn(){      
     logger.info("started performUsersignIn");
     signInAgent.performSignIn(username,password);
     logger.info("finished performUsersignIn");      
}
```

can this even be done ?

Comment: This can indeed be done using Spring AOP. Take a look at spring docs for more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `@Around` advice. Sample code should look like something below

```
@Aspect
public class MethodLogging {

@Around(execution("@annotation(LogMessage)"))
public Object logStartAndEnd(ProceddingJoinPoint pjp){
    String name = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    logger.info("started " + name);
    Object obj = pjp.proceed();
    logger.info("finished " + name); 
    return obj;
}

}
```

Refer the respective java docs for additional information.